# Writing formatter for type Any in scala-forms?

Tags: forms, scala, formatter

I want to create scala forms similar to this

```
val conditionMapping = mapping(
    "rkey" -> optional(text),
    "rflag" -> optional(of(EnumUtils.enumFormatter(InplaceNotifyFlag))),
    "rval" -> optional(of[Any])
  )(InplaceNotifyOnCondition.apply)(InplaceNotifyOnCondition.unapply)
```

but the formatter for Any is not available, how to solve this problem?

Comment: That would completely defeat the principle of typeclass, and so break the API

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the play framework, because you did not specify where that comes from.

Play uses the invariant `Formatter[A]` typeclass to find a `Formatter` for a type A.  Many formatters come builtin inside play.api.data.format.Formats.

In order to support `Any`, you therefore would have to write a new instance of the `Formatter` typeclass:

```
implicit val anyFormatter: Formatter[Any] = new Formatter[Any] {
  // define the bind and unbind method
}
```

But as cchantep said, that is probably not what you want to do, because this implicit is too general and will accept `Any` in cases where you don't want that.

Instead I would suggest to not have `Any` at all in your `InplaceNotifyOnCodnition` class.  Instead, wrap the `Any` in a case class for your specific use case and write a Formatter instance for that:

```
case class InplaceNotifyOnCondition(rkey: ..., rflag: ..., rval: Option[AnyRVal)

case class AnyRVal(rval: Any) extends AnyVal

object AnyRVal {
  implicit val rvalFormatter: Formatter[AnyRVal] = new Formatter[AnyRVal] {
    // implement
  }
}
```